# django with mysql model string array field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to design a model *Card* that should expect a request like following:

```
{"thing":"Book","responsibilities":["Name","ISBN"],"collaborators":[""]}
```

So far I designed my model like following:

```
class Responsibility(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )

class Collaborator(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )


class Card(models.Model):
    thing = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )
    responsibilities = models.ForeignKey(Responsibility, related_name='res_cards', blank=True, )
    collaborators = models.ForeignKey(Collaborator, related_name='col_cards', blank=True, )
```

but somehow having name attribute on other two models seems unnecessary for such a simple case. Can I design my model better to accept request like above?

Comment: unnecessary in what sense you..i mean you want to create only one model??

Comment: I don't understand what you really want to ask but note that you are using the foreign keys incorrectly. Your current design allows one card to have only one responsibility.

Comment: I think OP wants to know if they can create a model with no fields. In that case I believe `class Collaborator(models.Model): pass` will do the job of creating a model with only an ID.

Comment: @Ash so with pass where will the values i.e. Name, Age will go?

Comment: If it's the case that you want names on some models and not on others then you just need to set a default value - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#default - if that still doesn't solve your issue then I'm not sure what you are asking - please edit your question with `age` as there is no `age` on your initial question...

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to say this, but Django doesn't have ArrayField when if DB is MySql.
It has ArrayField if DB is Postgresql.
[Here you can see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/)